# how to add a simple attribute in the body as Name=Value in post response netty 4

Tags: java, netty

How can i add a simple attribute in the body as Name=Value  in the post response in netty 4.

In post request i find a class HttpPostRequestEncoder  where we have a method: addBodyAttribute(String name, String value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the example in https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload

Note however that a response is not a request and that in HTTP standard, only request contains attributes.

See the client example and in particular the `formpost` method on how to use `HttpPostRequestEncoder`: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/upload/HttpUploadClient.java

Still, if you want to put in the body Name=Value, the simplest is to build a `DefaultFullHttpResponse` like this:

```
ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer("Name=Value", CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK, buf);
```

Comment: thanks . I dont know  that in HTTP standard, only request contains attributes.